# append form rows using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Hello I have an HTML form and want to be able to add or delete rows dynamically.
ie just by a click on an Icon or a text the entire form row should be duplicated and by clicking on a text or icon the duplicated row should be deleted.
I know JavaScript append can solve this but I don't know how to implement it since my my HTML has needed php tags in them.
the drop-downs options are getting it values from a db and some other input fields are also getting it's values from a db hence the reason I have PHP tags in there.
Below is the attached code.
Kindly help me with how I can append the row with the appended form working just like the parent row

```html
<div class="col-xl-8 col-md-12">
        <form>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title"><strong class="text-success" style="cursor: pointer;"><?=ucwords($clientName)?></strong> REP'S INFORMATION</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label">Reps Name<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label">E-Mail<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" name="" class="form-control" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label">Phone No.<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text text-dark"  class="form-control" name="client_contact2" required="" id="client_contact2"  onkeypress="return restrictAlphabets(event)" onpaste="return false;" ondrop="return false;" autocomplete="off" required="">
                                <input type="date" name="" value="<?=date("Y-m-d")?>" hidden="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">ADD DEVICE(S) INFORMATION</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php 
                        if ($clientType === $slaClient) {
                    ?>
                        <table id='dyntbl' class='table border text-nowrap text-md-nowrap table-striped mb-0'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center" >Device Brand</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Device Model</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Serial Number</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width:10%">SLA Device</th>
                                    <th><button type="button" class=" btn text-success" data-name='add'><i class="fe fe-plus-circle" data-id='ad' style="font-size:1.6em;"></i></button></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="field_wrapper " id="table_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control form-select brand" data-bs-placeholder="Select" name="brand[]" required="" id="brand" onchange="checkDeviceStatus()">
                                            <?php 
                         $readALL = "SELECT * FROM productbrands WHERE deleted = 0";
                         $displayAll = mysqli_query($conn,$readALL);
                         while($rowFetchAll = mysqli_fetch_array($displayAll)){
                          $brandName = $rowFetchAll['brandName'];
                          $brandid = $rowFetchAll['brandID'];
                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?=$brandid?>"><?=$brandName?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control form-select model" data-bs-placeholder="Select" name="model[]" required="" id="model" onchange="checkDeviceStatus()">
                                            <?php 
                       $readALL1 = "SELECT * FROM productmodels WHERE deleted = 0";
                       $displayAll1 = mysqli_query($conn,$readALL1);
                       while($rowFetchAll1 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayAll1)){
                        $modelName = $rowFetchAll1['modelName'];
                        $modelid = $rowFetchAll1['modelID'];
                      ?>
                                            <option value="<?=$modelid?>"><?=$modelName?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="serialNo" class="form-control serialNo" id="serialNo" onchange="checkDeviceStatus()"></td>
                                    <!-- The input field below is to get value from AJAX -->
                                    <td><input type="text" name="deviceLevel" class="form-control" readonly="" id="deviceLevel"> 
                                        <!-- End of Input field -->
                                        </td>
                                        <input type="text" name="" id="client" value="<?=$clientID?>" hidden="" class="client">
                                    <td><button type="button"  class=" btn text-danger" data-name="del"><i class="fe fe-minus-circle"  style="font-size:1.6em;"></i></button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php
                        if ($clientType === $nonSla) {
                    ?>
                        <table  class='table border text-nowrap text-md-nowrap table-striped mb-0'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product Model Non-SLA</th>
                                    <th>Serial Number Non-SLA</th>
                                    <th>Device Status Non-SLA</th>
                                    <th><button type="button" class=" btn text-success" data-name='add'><i class="fe fe-plus-circle" data-id='ad' style="font-size:1.6em;"></i></button></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="field_wrapper " id="table_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" ></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td><button type="button"  class=" btn text-danger" data-name="del"><i class="fe fe-minus-circle"  style="font-size:1.6em;"></i></button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you use JS to copy a row that's already there, the dropdowns etc will already exist and be populated, so the PHP won't matter. Remember the PHP code already executed before the page was loaded into the browser, and generated some HTML. JS can copy that HTML output.

Comment: @ADyson I don't get you. how do I copy using JS

Comment: @ADyson if I copy or clone the ID's will be duplicated and won't be unique

Comment: True. But you can give items a new ID during the process. Or, don't use IDs - do you really need them for anything?

Comment: I am using ajax to get values for a particular input field. I can use class instead of ID's but I tried cloning the table but the ajax response does not work uniquely for the cloned rows. the parent role only works better as expected where as the children rows does not work

Comment: Instead of cloning a row, provide raw HTML as data attribute in the button. and when the button is clicked, get the `data-raw-html` value and then append the row into the table body. you can also pass the replacers in raw HTML and then you can replace some values dynamically on JS.

Comment: `the ajax response does not work uniquely for the cloned rows`...if AJAX code is involved, you'd likely need to adapt that too, yes, or at least the code which identifies the place where the data should be written. You need to put a bit of thought into it. You can identify DOM elements relative to other elements...

Comment: Remember: you will have to escape the string when passing into `data-raw-html` otherwise, you can just create a variable in JS with raw HTML and use it when the button is clicked.

Comment: @ADyson can you please demonstrate what you are saying

Comment: @VijayHardaha 
kindly demonstrate what you are saying please

Comment: @CephasArmah Added an example snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is basic example:

```js
const table_row_html = `
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ROW_NO}}</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-select" name="modal[]"">
                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                <option value=" 1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>`;

$(document).on("click", ".table a.insert", function() {
  const table_body = $(this).closest(".table").find("tbody");

  table_body.append(
    table_row_html.replace("{{ROW_NO}}", table_body.children("tr").length + 1)
  );
  return false;
});
$(document).on("click", ".table a.delete", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">
          <a class="btn btn-primary insert" href="#">Add</a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-select" name="modal[]" ">
                        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                        <option value=" 1 ">One</option>
                        <option value="2 ">Two</option>
                        <option value="3 ">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete " href="# ">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```